# rdlc expression iif use?

Tags: rdlc

In an rdlc report I want to compare integers  like

```
if(expression)
{
     // do something
}
else if(expression)
{
     // do something else
}
```

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 46):

Rather than using nested *IIF* statements I prefer the *Switch* statement.

From the MSDN...

```
=Switch(
    Fields!PctComplete.Value >= 10, "Green", 
    Fields!PctComplete.Value >= 1, "Blue", 
    Fields!PctComplete.Value = 1, "Yellow", 
    Fields!PctComplete.Value <= 0, "Red"
    )
```

Hope it helps **:)**

Comment: Thanks it's work 
Now i have another problem hope you help me ...

I have three type board LIKE:GOOD,REMOVED,NOTFOUND.....i want a report on rdlc that show me Board type amount like below
Thana   Good Removed NotFound
A          5   2       4
B          4   1       0

how can i do that

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean? Can you rephrase the the question in any way, your example has lost its formatting because its a comment.

Answer (score 9):

You will have to nest IIF statements like this:

```
 = IIF (expression = 1, "Is 1", IIF (expression = 2, "Is 2"))
```

Comment: thannks now if i want to compare string then? what i do....
like 

int Total=0
if(expression=="Good") then TotalIncrease

Comment: You cant have variables in that sense. You would nest the 'IIF' within a SUM or some other kind of aggregate function... =Sum(IIF(expression = "Good", 1, 0)). Something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use switch instead. I know I reached late here,but hope that it may help someone.

```
=Switch(Fields!Parameter.value = 2,"somethingnew", 1=1 ,"somethingelse")
```

1=1 refers to default in switch case.

It is similar like

```
if(Parameter.Value == 2)
{
somethingnew
}
else
{
somethingelse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Syntax for your requirement:

```
=IIf(CInt(Fields!expression1.value)==1,true,IIf(Cint(Fields!expression2.value)==2,true,nothing))
```

In true part you can specify the statement to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said, the `If(condition, true_part, false_part)` *ternary operator* should (with one `I`) be preferred over the `IIf(condition, true_part, false_part)` *function* (with two `I`'s) in most cases.

The [`If()` ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) will short-circuit evaluate only the part that corresponds to condition outcome (e.g. a condition that is `True` will only evaluate the `true_part`).

The `IIf()` function will always evaluate the condition and both parts, because it is just a function call and all parameters of the function will be evaluated before the call.

Since developers usually expect short-circuit evaluation in IF statements, the usage of the `If()` ternary operator should be the default choice.
It allows you to run expressions that check for `Nothing`, like the following, which would not work without lazy evaluation:

```vb
=If(Fields!Blog.Value IsNot Nothing, Fields!Blog.Value.Name, "Blog is missing")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this example

`= IIF(Parameters!expression.Value = True, 'somethingnew', 'somethingelse')`