# rdlc (piechart) customized colors for different segments

Tags: rdlc

I have written a code like below, my problem was sometimes I am getting same color for different segments in the piechart if the value came from the same range.
ref:
[rdlc expression iif use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999852/rdlc-expression-iif-use)
my code sample

```
=SWITCH(Fields!ID__Share_of_Costs.Value <= 0.99, "Yellow",
Fields!ID__Share_of_Costs.Value <= 30, "Teal",
Fields!ID__Share_of_Costs.Value <= 60, "SteelBlue",
Fields!ID__Share_of_Costs.Value <= 100, "Crimson",
 )
```

for eg: suppose my chart value is dynamic and it will come like 22 and 29, in this case the segment will show the same color (<= 30, "Teal",) as it is difficult to differntiate. Is there is any way to give different colors for each segment like no repeated color ?

Thanks in advance...cheers

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean by segment (range of values or particular value) or in other words is number of your segments limited?
If yes, then you could set up as much segments as you want with particular color.
If no, then write a custom function which will return hex value as your color.