# How to check multiple conditions in rdlc expression

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, iif-function

I have worked on only possible 2 in rdlc Expression values  as like

```
=iif((Fields!Gender.Value="1"),"Male","Female")
```

Here I can work with only 2 possibilities. But if I want to check 3 or more conditions than how can I?

Comment: Would you please mark the correct answer to help others find solution?

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy funny how this question was asked in 2012, mans been active last week and still hasn't "found his solution"

Answer (score 13):

Use the Switch if you have more conditions, it is also more readable.

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Gender.Value = 1, "Male", 
    Fields!Gender.Value = 2, "Female"
    )
```

[rdlc expression iif use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999852/rdlc-expression-iif-use)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `Code` property of the report. Right-click a blank space outside your report and click `Report Properties` or click the Report menu and click report properties.

Click the "Code" tab and type your condition checking statement as below

```
Public Function GetGender(ByVal val as String) As String
   Dim retVal as String = ""

   If(val = "1")
    retVal = "Male"
   Else If (val = "2")
    retVal = "???"
   Else If (val = "3")
    retVal = "???"
   Else
    retVal = "???"
   End If

   Return retVal

End Function
```

Then call the function in the expression of your textbox

```
= Code.GetGender(Fields!Gender.Value)
```

Comment: Hey this is very good option to enter write a code in report.thanx..i found other solution of using the switch statement just like iif.even this will work

Comment: You mean `IIf` in one line in the expression box? That is hard to debug but it's useful too

Answer (score 6):

try this one :

```
=iif(Fields!Gender.Value="1","Male", iif(Fields!Gender.Value="2","Female","Undefined"))
```

the format is :

```
=iif(expression=value, true, false)
```

you can change with :

```
=iif(expression=value, true, iif(expression2=value2, true, false))
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch and Custom Code look's nice, Thank you Guys

But if you insist using iif() condition  then,

```
=iif( (Fields!Gender.Value="1"), "Male", iif( (Fields!Gender.Value="2"), "Female", "Something Else" ) )
```

Ok, Bye