# How to use IIF command in code in rdl rdlc viewer?

Tags: rdlc

So I previously found this post 
[How to check multiple conditions in rdlc expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648434/how-to-check-multiple-conditions-in-rdlc-expression)
which had this code inside:

```
Public Function GetGender(ByVal val as String) As String 
  Dim retVal as String = ""   
  If(val = "1") 
  retVal = "Male"
  Else If (val = "2")
  retVal = "???"
  Else If (val = "3")
  retVal = "???"
  Else
  retVal = "???"
  End If
 Return retVal
End Function
```

This code works, but instead of (val="1") I need something like (val = "th*") that it searches and replaces anything that contains th, for example

Comment: Looks like VB. Try `val.StartsWith("th")`?

Comment: This is not c#. Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VB. Try `val.StartsWith("th")` – Caius Jard

This was the answer, thank you a lot Caius.!! 
I am new to stackoverflow so I'm still learning how to use this site.