# How to use multiple expressions for RDLC Visibility

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm trying to implement multiple `IF` conditions for the hidden expression for a text box in my `RDLC`. It works with one condition but not multiple.

Here is my code:

```
=IIF(Fields!CountDiffMorn.Value >1 or Fields!CountDiffNoon.Value >1 or Fields!CountDiffEve.Value >1 or Fields!CountDiffNight.Value >1,false,true)
```

I also tried nested IIF:

```
=iif(Fields!CountDiffMorn.Value <=1,true, iif(Fields!CountDiffNoon.Value<=1,true, 
iif(Fields!CountDiffEve.Value <=1,true,
iif(Fields!CountDiffNight.Value <=1,true,false))))
```

I want the text box to be visible if the Value is greater than one for any of these fields.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you have this test twice Fields!CountDiffNoon.Value >1 consider if elseif end if structure

Comment: Sorry was a typo, should be Fields!CountDiffNight.Value >1.

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648434/how-to-check-multiple-conditions-in-rdlc-expression I like the last answer all look workable