# Putting if condition in reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

i am using RDLC reports in asp.net c#, i am using expressions like IIF conditions etc, i have used this condition

```
=iif(Fields!TimeFrame.Value <= 24 AND Fields!TimeFrame.Value >=0 , "Yes", "No")
```

it works but i just want to handle one another condition what if value returned is =-1 then ?

i want to put condition like if Value= -1 then "Not Yet Received" but it doesn't work like the way i am thinking, help in putting condition,

how to put another `if condition` or any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to nest two `iif`s expression for example (formatted for readability) :

```
=iif(
      Fields!TimeFrame.Value = -1
      , "Not Yet Received"
      , iif(Fields!TimeFrame.Value <= 24 AND Fields!TimeFrame.Value >=0 , "Yes", "No")
    )
```

Above expression means if value equals `-1` then return "Not Yet Received", else check another `if` condition which return "yes" or "no".

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? no error or any other kind of clue? Another possible option is using `switch` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/999882/2998271

Comment: one question, why there is an outer iif which surrounds internal iff, shouldn't it be isolated iif then another iif etc ?

Answer (score 0):

=IIF((Fields!Mrmb.Value>0 AND Fields!Cn.Value>0),Fields!Mrmb.Value,IIF((Fields!Cn.Value>0 AND Fields!BchrA.Value>0), Fields!Ovrtme.Value,Fields!Bns.Value))

you can check this.

Comment: sorry it's not clear and expressive, i don't understand